# Display TIFF Format image in Android App

Tags: android, image, tiff

I was only able to find one previous post regarding this, and the provided answer did not seem to work correctly.  Is there ANY way to show a TIFF image with pinch / zoom ability in Android?  Writing an app and I need to show a TIFF image.

Comment: Are you looking for a free/paid solution? Can it be a complete app or are you looking for a library to link into your app? You can launch the free version of my app with an intent and it will do what you need (Fast Image Viewer).

Comment: Hi BitBank,How do you open your Image Viewer with an intent from within an activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be, in fact, a way to display a TIFF image on Android even though that format isn't supported by ImageView.

Take a look at this [project](https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, we've decided to convert the TIFF image into a JPEG server side before pulling it into the app, just to make life simpler.  However, if we would have needed the TIFF to be brought in, I would have used your suggestion so I have marked it as accepted.

Comment: If your TIFF images are bitonal, converting to JPEG will cause a large waste in resources - bandwidth, memory, time. Did you try using my "Fast Image Viewer" and opening it as an intent?

Comment: [Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory](https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory) works like a charm.

Comment: If you convert TIFF image to JPEG, please keep in mind that there can be data loss, as there can be multi page TIFF, which JPEG cannot support.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show tiff images in your android app but don't want to build native components, look there https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory
Is my library for working with tiff.