# tif and tiff images are not displaying android with Image component of react native

Tags: android, image, react-native

All images types are working even gif also but tif and tiff images are not getting displayed in android with Image component of react native.

For gif I used fresco:animated-gif but is there any other way for tif and tiff.
I used only Image in render and also tif is my local image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display TIFF Format image in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488958/display-tiff-format-image-in-android-app)

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem using this native lib: https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory

I've made my own class converter in Java Android, following this doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android, and invoking that class on React, converting my tiff image for png.

I'd created a NPM package for do that too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-tiff